# Fast rectangle to rectangle intersection

Tags: javascript, c++, language-agnostic, graphics

What's a fast way to test if 2 rectangles are intersecting?

---

A search on the internet came up with this one-liner (WOOT!), but I don't understand how to write it in Javascript, it seems to be written in an ancient form of C++.

```
struct
{
    LONG    left;
    LONG    top;
    LONG    right;
    LONG    bottom;
} RECT; 

bool IntersectRect(const RECT * r1, const RECT * r2)
{
    return ! ( r2->left > r1->right
        || r2->right < r1->left
        || r2->top > r1->bottom
        || r2->bottom < r1->top
        );
}
```

Comment: I think you've made a typo in your copy/paste

Comment: Well, this is where its from and it looks the same to me -- http://tekpool.wordpress.com/2006/10/11/rectangle-intersection-determine-if-two-given-rectangles-intersect-each-other-or-not/

Comment: The original article has a typo. `r2->right left` doesn't make sense. It's might be broken due to HTML escaping issues.

Comment: I'm curious how you think the above code would be different in a "modern" form of C++.

Comment: I'm sure the missing characters are `<` symbols due to html escaping.

Comment: @jamesdlin you would make the function as a member function of the struct, taking one parameter. Secondly you normally would use const& instead of const*. You might use templates to have both int, long, and double versions, instead of using some Win32 macro... (It does not compile either, as RECT ends up being an instance of an unnamed struct, not a type name.) Example: http://ideone.com/bnzwl3

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about trivial translation of source code into another language.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's C.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

This is how that code can be translated to JavaScript. Note that there is a typo in your code, and in that of the article, as the comments have suggested. Specifically `r2->right left` should be `r2->right < r1->left` and `r2->bottom top` should be `r2->bottom < r1->top` for the function to work.

```js
function intersectRect(r1, r2) {
  return !(r2.left > r1.right ||
    r2.right < r1.left ||
    r2.top > r1.bottom ||
    r2.bottom < r1.top);
}

// Test case:

var rectA = {
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  right: 30,
  bottom: 30
};

var rectB = {
  left: 20,
  top: 20,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 50
};

var rectC = {
  left: 70,
  top: 70,
  right: 90,
  bottom: 90
};

console.log(intersectRect(rectA, rectB)); // returns true
console.log(intersectRect(rectA, rectC)); // returns false
```

Comment: Just to add/confirm - this is testing three boxes that are 20px x 20px, except rectB, which is 30px x 30px

Comment: if r1 and r2 are identical, the intersectRect function would return false

Comment: Fantastic Eloquent Implementation. Love it! +1, worked perfectly for my game.

Comment: @zumalifeguard Why do you think that?

Comment: This function is so genius. I would have never thought of that, instead I would have tried to make the two boxes intersect.

Answer (score 77):

```
function intersect(a, b) {
  return (a.left <= b.right &&
          b.left <= a.right &&
          a.top <= b.bottom &&
          b.top <= a.bottom)
}
```

This assumes that the `top` is normally less than `bottom` (i.e. that `y` coordinates increase downwards).

Comment: Good and working solution, but should be a bit slower since all conditions have to be evaluated. The other solution is done as soon as one of the conditions evaluates to true.

Comment: This one is also done as soon as one of the conditions evaluates to false. I.e. in the exact same cases as the other one.

Comment: This is better as it removes the negation action.

Comment: +1, as much neater than the accepted answer.  if using half-open ranges (i.e. rectangle includes top and left but does not include bottom and right, as is common in many graphics systems), changing `<=` to `<` should work.

Comment: I like this solution because I can remove the `=` for each condition and it allows the rectangles to "touch" on the borders.

Answer (score 22):

This is how the .NET Framework implements Rectangle.Intersect

```
public bool IntersectsWith(Rectangle rect)
{
  if (rect.X < this.X + this.Width && this.X < rect.X + rect.Width && rect.Y < this.Y + this.Height)
    return this.Y < rect.Y + rect.Height;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Or the static version:

```
public static Rectangle Intersect(Rectangle a, Rectangle b)
{
  int x = Math.Max(a.X, b.X);
  int num1 = Math.Min(a.X + a.Width, b.X + b.Width);
  int y = Math.Max(a.Y, b.Y);
  int num2 = Math.Min(a.Y + a.Height, b.Y + b.Height);
  if (num1 >= x && num2 >= y)
    return new Rectangle(x, y, num1 - x, num2 - y);
  else
    return Rectangle.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another more simple way. (This assumes the y-axis increases downwards).

```
function intersect(a, b) {
  return Math.max(a.left, b.left) < Math.min(a.right, b.right) &&
          Math.max(a.top, b.top) < Math.min(a.bottom, b.bottom);
}
```

The 4 numbers (max's and min's) in the condition above also give the intersection points.

Answer (score 1):

This has a Rect type you can use.
It is already JavaScript.

https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-beta/source/toolkit/modules/Geometry.jsm

Comment: This code will return false for rects A(0,0,100,100) & B(100,100,100,100). I think theres should be <= instead of <

Comment: <= gives a rectangle with a height of 0. Not useful for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I used a blend of methods, to detect a smaller rectangle inside a large rectangle. This is a nodejs method and uses width/height but can easily be adapted.

```
            isIntersectingRect: function (r1, r2) {
              var quickCheck = (r1.x <= r2.x + r2.w &&
                      r2.x <= r1.x + r1.w &&
                      r1.y <= r2.y + r2.h &&
                      r2.y <= r1.y + r1.h)
              if (quickCheck) return true;
              var x_overlap = Math.max(0, Math.min(r1.x + r1.w, r2.x + r2.w) - Math.max(r1.x, r2.x));
              var y_overlap = Math.max(0, Math.min(r1.y + r1.h, r2.y + r2.h) - Math.max(r1.y, r2.y));
              var overlapArea = x_overlap * y_overlap;
              return overlapArea == 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The current .NET way is simply

```
    public bool IsEmpty => _width < 0.0;   

    public bool IntersectsWith(Rect rect)
    {
        if (IsEmpty || rect.IsEmpty)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (rect.Left <= Right && rect.Right >= Left && rect.Top <= Bottom)
        {
            return rect.Bottom >= Top;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified the accepted answer for a regular coordinate system (y axis grows up)

```
public static bool AARectsOverlap(float2 r1bl, float2 r1tr, float2 r2bl, float2 r2tr)
{
    return !(r2bl.x > r1tr.x || r2tr.x < r1bl.x || r2tr.y < r1bl.y || r2bl.y > r1tr.y);
}
```