# Hide div when reached element show when passed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for ideas to hide a div when it reaches another div and show it again when it passes the same div. There can also be multiple divs to pass. Something like:

```
 var bottom = $('.out-of-grid-images')

 $(window).scroll(function(){    
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > bottom){ 
            $('.share-icons').fadeOut(200); // hide share icons when reached and overlaps
        }
        else if ($(this).scrollTop() < bottom){ {
            $('.share-icons').fadeIn(200); // show icons when passed element
        }
    });
```

I can not produce a jsFiddle because I haven't found anything similar to work with. Any ideas?

EDIT:

The share icons are a fixed position element. The elements reached are dynamic and not fixed from top of the page (they are post content images out of the grid)

EDIT: here's an image to illustrate the matter
[image]

Comment: Are other `<div>`s are fixed?

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Use `if ($(this).scrollTop() > bottom.offset().top) ...`

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is have an `Array` of divs that you want to trigger the hiding effect, then calculate their bounding rectangle, and then perform collision detection on them.

Here is a very rough example - you'll have to fix the showing and hiding, as this will cause a fadeIn/fadeOut on each scroll event.

```
const shareIcons = $('.share-icons');
const divs = $('.trigger-div');
const rects = [];

divs.each(function () {
    rects.push(this.getBoundingClientRect());
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    let interectsAny = false;
    rects.forEach(function (rect) {
        if (intersectRect(rect, shareIcons[0].getBoundingClientRect())) {
            interectsAny = true;
        }
    });
    if (interectsAny) {
        shareIcons.fadeOut(200);
    } else {
        shareIcons.fadeIn(200);
    }
});

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752349/fast-rectangle-to-rectangle-intersection
function intersectRect(r1, r2) {
  return !(r2.left > r1.right || 
           r2.right < r1.left || 
           r2.top > r1.bottom ||
           r2.bottom < r1.top);
}
```