# JavaScript works exclusively inline

Tags: javascript

This collision code (referenced verbatim from Mozilla) works:

```
if (rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width &&
   rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
   rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height &&
   rect1.height + rect1.y > rect2.y) {
    // collision detect!
    //do something, like this...
    rect1.x + 100;
}
```

However, if written as a function, it never rings true (nothing happens).

Function:

```
function MozillaCollision(ObjectA, ObjectB) {
    if (ObjectA.x < ObjectB.x + ObjectB.width && ObjectA.x + ObjectA.width > ObjectB.x && ObjectA.y < ObjectB.y + ObjectB.height && ObjectA.height + ObjectA.y > ObjectB.y) {
        // collision detected!
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Calling the function:

```
if (MozillaCollision(rect1, rect2))
{
    //do something, like this...
    rect1.x + 100;
}
```

Nothing ever happens, despite the code working when it's outside of a function/written inline!

If I change the function call by moving its brackets slightly, like this, then it is constantly being called true (rect1 is constantly moving by 100 pixels on the x axis, despite the fact that rect1 and rect2 aren't actually colliding, so I can only assume that this is not how functions are written!):

```
if (MozillaCollision)(rect1, rect2)
{
    //do something, like this...
    rect1.x + 100;
}
```

The fact that it either executes constantly or not at all depending upon placement of brackets is confusing (I'm learning the syntax). This confusion is exacerbated by the fact that the collision code works just fine when it is not written as a function that is being called.

My question, then, is about the correct JavaScript syntax for writing functions. I'm seemingly writing this wrong (code works otherwise sans being in a function), and any clarification's appreciated.

Comment: I can tell you the two comparisons line up.  Perhaps if you provide a couple sample objects it would be easier for us to help.

Comment: I can't get the original code to work.  You might be interested in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752349/fast-rectangle-to-rectangle-intersection

Comment: Did the solution below resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to have a syntax error (or mistake) that would result in nothing happening. Here's the code in question:

```
rect1.x + 100;
```

which would evaluate to `102` but not actually do anything. My guess is you want to increment `rect1.x` by `100`, which would be done with:

```
rect1.x += 100;
```

This minor error/mistake is the cause of the remaining issues you're seeing. That is, `rect1.x + 100` merely evaluates to `102` but doesn't change anything. The code would have to be changed to `rect1.x += 100` for `rect1` to cause `rect1.x` to be updated.

Once we made this fix we can add some console logs to see what's happening:

```js
function mozillaCollides(object1, object2) {
  if (object1.x < object2.x + object2.width &&
    object1.x + object1.width > object2.x &&
    object1.y < object2.y + object2.height &&
    object1.height + object1.y > object2.y) {
    // collision detect!
    //do something, like this...
    rect1.x += 100;
    console.log(rect1, 'inside the mozillaCollides function');
  }
}

const rect1 = {
  x: 2,
  y: 2, 
  height: 2,
  width: 2
}

const rect2 = {
  x: 5,
  y: 5, 
  height: 2,
  width: 2
}

const rect3 = {
  x: 3,
  y: 3, 
  height: 2,
  width: 2
}

mozillaCollides(rect1, rect2);
mozillaCollides(rect1, rect3);

console.log(rect1, 'outside the mozillaCollides function')
```

If you run the code you'll see 2 console logs, resulting from `mozillaCollides(rect1, rect3)` (since the rectangles collide in that case), showing that `rect1.x` has been updated to `102` (2 + 100).

To reiterate, with your existing code, using `rect1.x + 100`, nothing would change, so you were correct about that. If we change that statement to `rect1.x += 100` we then see a change to `rect1`.

Here's the other example you posted with the necessary change:

```js
function mozillaCollides(object1, object2) {
  if (object1.x < object2.x + object2.width &&
    object1.x + object1.width > object2.x &&
    object1.y < object2.y + object2.height &&
    object1.height + object1.y > object2.y) 
  {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

const rect1 = {
  x: 2,
  y: 2, 
  height: 2,
  width: 2
}

const rect2 = {
  x: 5,
  y: 5, 
  height: 2,
  width: 2
}

const rect3 = {
  x: 3,
  y: 3, 
  height: 2,
  width: 2
}

if (mozillaCollides(rect1, rect3)) {
  rect1.x += 100;
};

console.log(rect1)
```